# I can't return get 200 response from curl command

Tags: http, tomcat, curl

I have a web application running in my tomcat server. When type the url in the browser, the app is working fine :

[image]

But when I do it with the curl command :

```html
curl  -IL http://localhost:8090/mysite
```

I get the following :

```html
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow: GET
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 1047
Date: Sun, 20 Nov 2016 11:41:27 GMT
```

What I am missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without "-I" - maybe the server doesn't support HEAD (which would be a severe bug).

Comment: Well I get the body. But why? It's working fine in the browser.

Comment: Because the browser does a GET request, while you tried a HEAD request.